# What are the differences between all the python discord libraries

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like t ask what all the diferences are because i am quite confused. Iam trying to use the latest discord rewrite version but i dont know what i am using and how to check. Any clarification would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `discord.py` - A Python wrapper for the Discord API, the most powerful discord library you'll find for python
- `discord.py-rewrite` - `discord.py` above version `1.0`
- `discord.py-async` - `discord.py` from version `0.10` to `1.0`
- `discord` - A clone of `discord.py`
- `discord unofficial` - Another clone of `discord.py v0.16.12` with the new gateway intents

To check what version you have installed, in the command prompt

```
python -m discord -v
```

The only true discord library is `discord.py`, every other discord library is based on it.

I recommend you using `discord.py`.

[Pypi discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)

Comment: When i check with print(discord.__version__) i tells me 1.5.1 what does that mean?

Comment: The version of discord.py you're using

Comment: O so i am using the standard library and none of those based on it

Comment: That's right, if you installed it with `pip install discord.py`, also remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Thank you  i understand now. So you say discord.py is the best. Why shouldnt i use rewrite and what would be the pros and cons?

Comment: Well, the rewrite version is a lot better than async, also the async versions don't work anymore so you don't have any other option. There are a lot of pros of the rewrite branch, it's more intuitive, and a lot faster. [Here's the changelog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#migrating-1-0) if you wanna check it out. There are no cons imo.

Comment: I think i will start working with the newest rewrite and go from there thanks a lot for your help.